# Find the period where the number of occurrences is the highest

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table "events_log" in this form :

```
| id | started_at          | duration |
| 1  | 2017-06-01 09:00:00 | 80       |
| 1  | 2017-06-01 09:01:00 | 40       |
| 1  | 2017-06-01 09:01:23 | 20       |
```

I want to know when the most events were occuring (with a minute precision) :

```
|period               |count|
| 2017-06-01 09:00:00 | 1   |
| 2017-06-01 09:01:00 | 3   |
```

In reality, there a millions of events to handle.

My solution is to :

- Create a temporary table with event start grouped by minute
- LEFT JOINing it with the events between each period

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8546a/1

But performance is terrible ...

Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would think `group by`, something like this:

```
select date_format(started_at, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') as yyyymmddhhmi, count(*)
from t
group by yyyymmddhhmi
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

Performance will not be great.

Comment: This query count the events *started* grouped by period.But it wouldn't include events started *before* the period but ended *after*.

Comment: @Erwan In this case even your solutions doesn't return correct answer. If your last event will be longer than minute, it will be counted only for first minute. Better will be to generate timeline and then check what times on that timeline your event fits. Sad is that you still have to compute end_times.

Comment: @Erwan . . . Your question says nothing about duration and doesn't have an end date for the events (unless that is the purpose of the undefined `duration` column).  Starts seems like the most reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I should have said duration is in second.

Comment: @MarekVitek You're right that the last event will be counted once only. I'm OK with this, because I'm looking for the greatest occurences only. My first query is my base timeline (with missing datetimes, but that OK for my needs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified version of your code. It will scan through events_log table twice. Once when building event_starts helper table and second time when selecting all events that are happening in specified interval. Also note added index, that will significantly speed up execution. It might be also reason why your original query was so slow.

```
CREATE TABLE events_log (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,started_at DATETIME,duration INT(11));

INSERT INTO events_log (started_at, duration) VALUES ('2017-06-01 09:00:00', 80);
INSERT INTO events_log (started_at, duration) VALUES ('2017-06-01 09:01:00', 40);
INSERT INTO events_log (started_at, duration) VALUES ('2017-06-01 09:01:23', 20);


CREATE /* TEMPORARY */ TABLE tmp_event_starts AS (
select DISTINCT DATE_ADD(started_at, INTERVAL -SECOND(started_at) SECOND) AS period_start
from events_log
);

create index idx_tmp_event_starts
on tmp_event_starts (period_start);


select period_start, count(*), group_concat(id) from events_log as log
join tmp_event_starts as per
  on per.period_start >= DATE_ADD(started_at, INTERVAL -SECOND(started_at) SECOND)
  and per.period_start <= DATE_ADD(started_at, INTERVAL -SECOND(started_at)+duration SECOND)
  group by period_start
;
```

If you have lot of events happening in same minute and there are not minutes without events, then you might consider generating helper table as a sequence of minutes independent of data. In MySql it is quite uneasy task, but some hints can be found in this blog post [Calendar Tables: An Invaluable Database Tool](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)
It will also allow for generating helper table in advance and thus speeding up execution of query itself significantly.
You might also consider adding ended_at columnt to your event_log table, which will eliminate need for conversion during query execution.